# Put space between row for bootstrap image gallery

Tags: html, row, bootstrap-modal, image-gallery

I am using bootstrap and i want to create space between row 1 and row 2. There are 6 images together and row 1 and 2 has 3 images in each row

This is my code for each image

```html
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 ">
          <img src="images/1thumb.png" alt="Main">
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 ">
          <img src="images/2thumb.jpg" alt="Elevator1">
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 ">
          <img src="images/3thumb.jpg" alt="Elevator2">
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 ">
          <img src="images/4thumb.jpg" alt="Elevator3">
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 ">
          <img src="images/5thumb.jpg" alt="Interior">
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 ">
          <img src="images/6thumb.jpg" alt="Reception">
        </div>

    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just add margin bottom to the columns.

Something like

```
.row > div { margin-bottom: 15px}
```